# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/PropertyAccessor

Tags: java, spring, noclassdeffounderror

//main Class

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
    public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    //BeanFactory _factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("check.xml"));        

    ApplicationContext _app = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("C:\\Users\\jpushpan\\Desktop\\JeffWorkSpace\\WorkSpace\\Test\\jeffSpring\\src\\check.xml");

    //TestClass _testi = (TestClass) _factory.getBean("test");
    TestClass _testi = (TestClass) _app.getBean("test");

    _testi.display();
}
```

}

//Test Class

```
 public class TestClass {

String _msg;

public String getName() {  
    return _msg;  
}

public void setMsg (String msg)
{
    this._msg= msg;
}
void display()
{
    System.out.println("Message : "+_msg);
}
```

}

//xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans  
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-.0.xsd">    

<bean id="test" class="jeffSpring.TestClass">  
<property name="msg" value="jeffAyan"></property>  
</bean>  

</beans>
```

> My code perfectly works with Bean factory
>   Buts shows "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/springframework/expression/PropertyAccessor" error with Application context class

Comment: Check if spring-expression.jar is available in classpath. More details : http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/65417-spring-3-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-expression-propertyaccessor

Comment: thanks abhijeet, i replaced the entire jar in the build path now it works fine.